# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear la tabla dinamica con datos de los campos de texto?

Tags: javascript, pgadmin

Estoy usando php y tengo una tabla dinámica. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para agregar datos a la tabla desde campos de textos?

> En este código está el script donde se crea la tabla. Lo que quiero hacer es que al darle agregar también se carguen el nombre, el código y la cantidad de los campos de textos que están sobre la tabla para luego crear un buscador.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing4", "root", "");
function fill_unit_select_box($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_unit ORDER BY unit_name ASC";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["unit_name"].'">'.$row["unit_name"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add Remove Select Box Fields Dynamically using jQuery Ajax in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Add Remove Select Box Fields Dynamically using jQuery Ajax in PHP</h3>
   <br />
   <h4 align="center">Enter Item Details</h4>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" /> <input type="text" name="precio" value="" /> <input type="text" name="cantidad" value="" />
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Enter Item Name</th>
       <th>Enter Quantity</th>
       <th>Select Unit</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_name[]" class="form-control item_name" /></td>';
  html += '<td><input type="text" name="item_quantity[]" class="form-control item_quantity" /></td>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Unit</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });

 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });

});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: necesito un script que tambien agrege a la tabla codigo nombre y cantidad al seleccionar el boton]

[image: CREACION DE LA TABLA DINAMICA]

Comment: alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: Por favor alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: Yo no entiendo que quieres hacer. Cuando le das al botón `+`, ¿qué se supone debe pasar?

Comment: Cuando le doy al boton + se debe crear la tabla dinamica con los datos de los campos de textos, codigo, nombre y cantidad no se como hacerlo

Comment: Parece que fue una mala mezcla, me di cuenta que hay como dos scripts, deberían haber estado dentro del html al crear una página web completamente del php. Pero, tienes que hacerlo de manera ordenada. Los script y el link deberían estar arriba del head.